# Switch AWS Accounts in the Ruby Shell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to access an s3 bucket from within the interactive ruby shell, using different AWS credentials than the ones the application is configured with.

I've tried manually setting a new s3 client using the other key/secret, but I get Access Denied as the call defaults to using the application's preconfigured AWS account. Modifying the application's configured credentials is not an option, as it's needed to simultaneously access different AWS resources.

Here's what I'm trying in the ruby shell:

```
s3_2 = AWS::S3.new(:access_key_id => "<key>", :secret_access_key => "<secret>")
bucket = s3_2.buckets['<bucket_name>']
bucket.objects.each do |obj|
  puts obj.key
end
```

(The test just does a get to confirm access, it works if I use public access on the bucket because it allows any AWS user, but not when I restrict it and try to use the new temporary user that has s3 full access on the account.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rails console should be a separately running instance of the app from the server instance using the pre-configured credentials.

The following should update the credentials for the rails console session only.

```
Aws.config.update({credentials:Aws::Credentials.new('your_access_key_id','your_secret_access_key')})
```

Comment: The problem with doing that is that the application is live and still needs to access the default config. I need a way to use a temporary config if that's a thing. That may be the answer, that you can't configure multiple aws accounts at the same time..

Answer (score 0):

A new AWS S3 client should be initialized:

`s3_2 = Aws::S3::Client.new(:access_key_id => "<key>", :secret_access_key => "<secret>")`